# Count length message field on Logstash

Tags: logstash, elk

I want to know the length of the message log and put it in as a new field on logstash event. for example:

**From this event**

```
{
    ...
       "message" => "[2021-12-22T04:41:20.151992+00:00] testing.INFO: Message error"
    ...
}
```

**Into this event**

```
{
    ...
       "message" => "[2021-12-22T04:41:20.151992+00:00] testing.INFO: Message error"
       "mes_leng" => 76
    ...
}
```

I've tried using filter with Ruby plugin and using code to extract the length, but nothing happen on the output logs.

Is this possible to manipulate this event on logstash? Many appreciate

Comment: You need the ruby filter to achieve something like that. Update your question with the ruby code you used in the ruby filter.

Answer (score 1):

hope this gonna help (tested on 7.16.X)

```
ruby {
  code => "event.set('message_length', event.get('message').length)" 
}
```

in your case with "mes_leng":

```
ruby {
  code => "event.set('msg_leng', event.get('message').length)" 
}
```